# Output the result of each loop in different columns

Tags: awk

`price.txt` file has two columns: (name and value)

```
Mary 134
Lucy 56
Jack 88
```

`range.txt` file has three columns: (fruit and min_value and max_value)

```
apple 57 136
banana 62 258
orange 88 99
blueberry 98 121
```

My aim is to test whether the value in `price.txt` file is between the min_value and max_value in `range.txt`. If yes, putout `1`, If not, output `"x"`.

I tried:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { name=$1; price[name]=$2; next} { 
     for (name in price) { 
         if ($2<=price[name] && $3>=price[name]) {print 1} else {print "x"}
     } 
 }' price.txt range.txt
```

But my results are all in one column, just like follows:

```
1
1
x
x
x
x
x
x
1
1
1
x
```

Actually, I want my result to be like: (Each name has one column)

```
1 x 1
1 x 1
x x 1
x x x
```

Because I need to use `paste` to add the output file and `range.txt` file together. The final result should be like:

```
apple 57 136 1 x 1
banana 62 258 1 x 1
orange 88 99 x x 1
blueberry 98 121 x x x
```

So, how can I get the result of each loop in different columns? And is there anyway to output the final result without `paste` based on my current code? Thank you.

Comment: The print statement appends ORS (by default new line) to its argument. You could use printf (e.g., printf("1")) for more control of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This builds on what you provided,

```
# load prices by index to maintain read order
FNR == NR {
    price[names++]=$2
    next
}
# save max index to avoid using non-standard length(array)
END {
    names=NR
}
{
 l = $1 " " $2 " " $3
 for (i=0; i < names; i++) {
     if ($2 <= price[i] && $3 >= price[i]) {
             l = l " 1"
     } else {
             l = l " x"
    }
 }
 print l
}
```

and generates output,

```
apple 57 136 1 x 1
banana 62 258 1 x 1
orange 88 99 x x 1
blueberry 98 121 x x x
```

However, you don't have the person name for the score (anonymous results) - maybe that's intentional?

The change here is to explicitly index array populated in first block to maintain order.

Comment: Thank you, @ocurran, actually i need the column to be arranged in "name" order (left to right is Mary, Lucy and Jack). I suddenly got an idea: is there any possibility to output the "1" and "x" as a string of character in each row? For example: the first line should be `apple 57 136 1x1`, `1x1` are arranged in the order of Mary, Lucy and Jack.

Comment: `length(array)` is part of POSIX now, it's no longer gawk-specific. never use a variable named `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` and so obfuscates your code. all awk builtin/generated arrays, functions, and strings start at 1, not 0, so start your manually created arrays at 1 too to avoid having to remember how your arrays were created later.