# Extract specific characters from a string in a loop in linux

Tags: bash, shell, awk

This is a new and further question based on:
[Output the result of each loop in different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39546484/output-the-result-of-each-loop-in-different-columns).

But since it is a new question, you don't need to look at the question in link, I will clearly clarify the new question below.

`money.txt` file has two columns: (name and money)

```
Mary 13
Lucy 8
Jack 20
```

`range.txt` file has three columns: (fruit, min_value and max_value)

```
apple 10 15
banana 7 12
orange 17 22
blueberry 14 22
```

My aim is to test whether the money in `money.txt` file is between the min_value and max_value in `range.txt`. If yes, print out the (`max_value` - `money`)th character of `fruit` in `range.txt`, If not, output `"x"`.

For example, `Mary` is `13` in the `money.txt`, `13` is within the min_value and max_value of `apple`, and the `max_value` - `money` value is `15` - `13` = `2`, so it should print out the 2nd character of `apple`, that is `p`.

The expected result is : (The 4th column is for Mary, the 5th column is for Lucy, and the 6th column is for Jack)

```
apple 10 15 p x x
banana 7 12 x a x
orange 17 22 x x r
blueberry 14 22 x x l
```

With @ocurran 's help, I tried:

```
# load prices by index to maintain read order
awk 'FNR == NR {
    money[names++]=$2
    next
}
# save max index to avoid using non-standard length(array)
END {
    names=NR
}
{
 l = $1 " " $2 " " $3
 for (i=0; i < names; i++) {
     if ($2 <= money[i] && $3 >= money[i]) {
             fruit=$1
             fruitcharacter=${fruit:($3-money[i]-1):1}
             l = l " " $fruitcharacter
     } else {
             l = l " x"
    }
 }
 print l
}' money.txt range.txt
```

The result showed that:

```
awk: line 14: syntax error at or near {
awk: line 16: syntax error at or near else
awk: line 19: syntax error at or near }
```

It seems that `fruitcharacter=${fruit:($3-money[i]-1):1}` can not work. But as I know, we can use `${string: index: length}` to extract the character of a string, I don't know why it can not work at this situation. Can you help me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Count 14 lines down from the start of your awk script and you get the line `fruitcharacter=${fruit:($3-money[i]-1):1}` which is syntactic nonsense to awk, hence the syntax error output message. You say "as I know, we can use `${string: index: length}` to extract the character of a string" but that's absolutely not true (hint: **awk is not shell!**). Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you! I do mix the some concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { money[NR]=$2; next }
{
    out = $0
    for (i=1; i in money; i++) {
        out = out OFS ( (money[i]>=$2) && (money[i]<=$3) ? substr($1,2,1) : "x" )
    }
    print out
}

$ awk -f tst.awk money.txt range.txt
apple 10 15 p x x
banana 7 12 x a x
orange 17 22 x x r
blueberry 14 22 x x l
```

and if you want some column headers and nicer output formatting:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { names[NR]=$1; money[NR]=$2; next }
FNR==1 {
    out = "Fruit" OFS "Min" OFS "Max"
    for (i=1; i in names; i++) {
        out = out OFS names[i]
    }
    print out
}
{
    out = $0
    for (i=1; i in money; i++) {
        out = out OFS ( (money[i]>=$2) && (money[i]<=$3) ? substr($1,2,1) : "x" )
    }
    print out
}

$ awk -f tst.awk money.txt range.txt | column -t
Fruit      Min  Max  Mary  Lucy  Jack
apple      10   15   p     x     x
banana     7    12   x     a     x
orange     17   22   x     x     r
blueberry  14   22   x     x     l
```

Comment: Thank you so much @EdMorton But I wonder what `substr($1,2,1)` means. Does it means extracting the second character of `$1` from `range.txt`? If so, it is not what I expected, I want to get the (`max_value` - `money`)th character of `$1` in `range.txt`.

Comment: Yes that's what it means. So if max_value is stored in `$3` and money is stored in `money[i]`, what do you think you have to do to `substr($1,2,1)` to get the `max_value - money`th character instead of the `2`nd character? Welcome to fishing 101 :-).

Comment: `substr($1,($3-money[i]),1)`    ^_^

Comment: There y'go. No parens needed but they don't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would not use `awk` for this and keep it IMHO quite simple:

```
#!/bin/bash

money=$(<money.txt)
range=$(<range.txt)

while read -r fruit min max; do
    echo -e "$fruit $min $max \c"
    while read -r name cash; do
        if (($cash > $min)) && (($cash < $max)); then
            pos=$(($max - $cash - 1))
            echo -e "${fruit:pos:1} \c"
        else
            echo -e "x \c"
        fi
    done <<< "$money"
    echo
done <<< "$range"
```

The output is exactly as you described for given source data, and the logic should work consistently for other data, too. :)

Comment: You should read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to learn a few of the reasons why you SHOULD use awk for this. Additionally your approach will be extremely slow as it reads money.txt many times. Don't use all-upper-case for non exported variables names by convention and to avoid clashing with builtin and exported names and since you're using math operators `((...))` for some of the script, just use then for all of it for clarity and concistency.

Comment: Point taken, I have rectified some of my bad habits. :) Initially when testing I had the data in variables as I did not want to bother to create them. Finally I just changed it to read from file to match the OP's question, did not realize that it would cause redundant reads from the disk.